# is user input supported in Jenkins scripted pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to use the `input` step to prompt users for a input string, I used scripted pipeline in my Jenkinsfile, i.e. the top level block is `node` rather than `pipeline`, but when I put this `input` step in the `stage` block, the blue ocean just report a failure rather than prompt me on the input.

Is the `input` step only supported in declarative, not scripted?

the code is below:

```
node {
  input {
    message "Should we continue?"
    ok "Yes, we should."
    parameters {
      string(name: 'PERSON', defaultValue: 'Mr Jenkins', description: 'Who should I say hello to?')
    }
  }
  echo "Hello, ${PERSON}"
}
```

Comment: If we would know your code or the error message, we could be even more helpful ;-)

Comment: There's a syntax difference.. as described by John, it's a directive in declarative pipelines and you use it in a `input { .. }` syntax. In scripted pipelines, you use it as a groovy function (`input(..)`) or - as usual in groovy - with the brackets left out.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, the `input` step is absolutely supported in scripted pipelines, as this is really a step and not a construct of a declarative pipeline.

EDIT after OP posted the code:

You are trying to use the declarative syntax (`input { .. }`) within a scripted pipeline. Correct would be:

```
input(message: "Should we continue?")
```

You find the documentation for the `input` step [here](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-input-step/#-input-%20wait%20for%20interactive%20input).

Comment: Hi, but when I use this in scripted pipeline, the blue ocean UI doesn't prompt me with a box to input my parameter. How could I solve this problem?

Comment: `input` is a __directive__ in **declarative pipelines**, as well as a __step__ that is available for  **scripted pipelines** (which can be used in a `script` block inside a `steps` directive with **declarative pipelines**

Comment: Thanks for correcting these details, John! zanyman, edit your question and add a minimal example how you encounter this problem. Input works well for me in both scripted and declarative pipelines.

Comment: I've updated the code which failed, could you tell me what is wrong with syntax?

Comment: As expected, you use declarative pipeline syntax in a scripted pipeline..